# Why does the "too many requests" error message no longer have error info?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, error-message

After a long while, I finally managed to get a "Too many requests" error message in my regular course of browsing the site.

However, this message used to include a lot of error info, which the message prompted to include in emails sent to support regarding the limiting. When I got this error today, though, the message didn't include any error info, and simply stated I made too many requests. The styling is also completely different from how it used to be: the logo icon has been removed, and the page has almost none of the text formatting it used to have.

Why was the error info in the message for too many requests removed?

Comment: Maybe you hit it in lower level than before? How did you get it? (i.e. what scripts have you been using that sent so many requests.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Had a question hit HNQ, was refreshing pages to see if my question was still on it or if it had slid off.

Comment: Refreshing manually? I refreshed 100 times manually once to check something with ad rotation, no block. Something here is weird beyond the message itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I guess my dynamic IP changed, and the previous user was repeatedly accessing SE? That said, I used to get this error way more frequently in the past because I had an extension that made an extra request every time I loaded a page. Halving that means I have only double room, which wasn't much.

Comment: Well if it keeps happening and makes it harder for you to use SE, worth sending contact us, they can see the logs and tell you exactly what's going on. As for message, well, that would still be a mystery.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Presumably they needed the error info to get the right part of the log? Without it, how can they do so?

Comment: Maybe more work, but they can extract relevant parts with your IP address.